# How to call run-local function from debot?

Tags: solidity, everscale

How to call run-local (without sending a message) function of another contract from debot? For example, for getting a public variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was useful for me.

In debot:

1. Create interface for function of another contract with function (if public variable too).

```
interface IOther {   
    function funcName()    
    external returns(uint);
}
```

2. Build the message and send it.

```
function runLocal() public{
        optional(uint256) pubkey = 0;                 
        address remoteContract = address.makeAddrStd(0, 0xceaa3bc6b00cf2b1e750dae2dd94d246a126a989009a3fb3bb73bea1a48b3b);                    
        TvmCell message = tvm.buildExtMsg({
            abiVer: 2,
            callbackId: tvm.functionId(onSuccessFuncName),
            onErrorId: tvm.functionId(onErrorFuncName),
            time: uint64(now),
            dest: remoteContract,
            call: {
                IOther.funcName
            }
            });
            tvm.sendrawmsg(message, 1);      
    }

    function onSuccessFuncName(uint response) public{                                        
        /* working with response from remote contract */
    } 
    
    function onErrorFuncName() public{        
       /* catch error */
    }
```